# Selecting Span Class Element

Tags: c#, html, css, selenium

Using Selenium / C#

I have an automated test case where a user logs in (jonpark2), once the user has done so their username is stored in the text of a span class, I need to select this element and then verify an assert on it.

I have the below to try and select this:

```
public static void Userloggedin()
{
    var userlogedin = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.ClassName("username"));
    var selectelement = new SelectElement(userlogedin);
    selectelement.SelectByText("JonPark2");
}
```

When I run this i encounter the error `OpenQa.Selenium.Support.UI.unexpectedTagNameException:Element should have been select but was div.`

The below html shows in more detail what I am trying to select:

```
<div class="content-wrapper"> 
  <div class="float-left">
    <div class="float-right"> 
      <section id="login">
        <p>
           <a title="Manage your account" class="username" href="Account/Manage">
             Text - Empty Text Node
               <span class="username">
                 Text - JonPark2
```

Can anyone point out where I have gone wrong ?

Comment: try to detect span from the parent element...

Answer (score 0):

You can select that element by XPath:

`var spanElement = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class, 'username')]"));`

And then take text:

`var textInSpan = spanElement.Text`

Comment: I have tried this, but this returns an error, Element should have been select but was span.

Comment: I think SelectElement is Class for <select> tag, not for <span>.
You shloud use some method (like GetAttribute("...")) on you userlogedin.

Comment: You should use getText() method :)

var userlogedin = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class, 'username')]"));

var textInSpan = userlogedin.getText();

Comment: I have GetAttribute, but not getText, am i missing a namespace ?

Comment: Then try userlogedin.Text;, or userlogedin.GetAttribute("innerHTML");

Comment: In the C# bindings it'll be `.Text`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select something that is not part of a `<select>`.

try this:

```
public static void Userloggedin()
{
    return (
        "JonPark2" == Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.cssSelector("section#login span.username")).Text;
    )
}
```

Comment: In c#, `Text` is a property, not a method.

Comment: fixed.  i don't use C# `:)`